# Linux non-blocking sockets

Tags: linux, asynchronous

Hello I want to implement non-blocking TCP sockets with an openSSL overlay. For now I use epoll, but isn't there another methode (except poll or select)? Is it possible to associate a callback function to a descriptor? I read something about `libaio`, but I don't know exactly what it can do...

Comment: http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aionotes.txt ... two clicks from google

Comment: Is there any reason why epoll doesn't work well enough for your situation?

Comment: Just use epoll.  Everyone does.  Or a wrapper like libevent or libev.

Comment: Ok epoll is the best solution then, because libevent is broken on my linux distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `epoll` functions from now on because it works very good. For any help check the corresponding manpages which are good documented.